# How do I convert ~24000 product titles into URL keys?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, shopify, gsub

I have an array with ~24000 products. The hash will be saved as a CSV and uploaded to a Shopify shop using the products import method.

When I manually create a single product, the product url key/handle is automatically generated based on the product title. When using the products import method (CSV), I'll have to specify it myself.

How do I convert the titles into product url keys?

Example:

```
title_1 = "AH Verse frietaardappelen"
url_key_1 = "ah-verse-frietaardappelen"

title_2 = "Lay's Sensations red sweet paprika"
url_key_2 = "lay-s-sensations-red-sweet-paprika"
```

I'm currently using:

```
<title>.downcase.gsub(' ','-').gsub("'", '-')
```

but this doesn't remove `%`, `$`, `&`, `/` etc. from the title. I want to make sure the url key/product handle is as clean as possible.

There must be a better way to do this, what could I try next?

Comment: try `title_2.downcase.gsub(/\W+/, '-')`

Comment: Why is this question put on hold? "Unclear what you're asking"? It can't get any clearer then this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a (private) [`to_handle`](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/master/performance/shopify/shop_filter.rb#L100) method in Shopify's Liquid gem:

```
def to_handle(str)
  result = str.dup
  result.downcase!
  result.delete!("'\"()[]")
  result.gsub!(/\W+/, '-')
  result.gsub!(/-+\z/, '') if result[-1] == '-'
  result.gsub!(/\A-+/, '') if result[0] == '-'
  result
end
```

Example:

```
to_handle("AH Verse frietaardappelen")
#=> "ah-verse-frietaardappelen"

to_handle("Lay's Sensations red sweet paprika")
#=> "lays-sensations-red-sweet-paprika"
```

Comment: This is the most clean and lightweight solution so far, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the gem [String Urlize](https://github.com/cheef/string-urlize), it may help you write a script to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Rails ActiveSupport::Inflector#parameterize solution - http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/parameterize

It handles a lot of edge cases and should work well for you.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to use **parameterize** method:

```
title_1 = "AH Verse $frietaardappelen".parameterize
         Output: "ah-verse-frietaardappelen"

title_2 = "Lay's Sensations red %sweet paprika".parameterize

    output: "lay-s-sensations-red-sweet-paprika"
```

Comment: I get `Ruby 1.9 doesn't support Unicode normalization yet
=> "ah-verse-frietaardappelen"`. The returned value is perect, but should I be worried about the "Ruby 1.9 doesn't support Unicode normalization yet" part?

Comment: @narzero which version do you use?

Comment: I use Ruby 2.1.2 with activesupport 2.3.18

Comment: Also which version of rails?

Comment: @narzero don't worry, parameterize method is support from rails version 3. so if you are using rails 3 then all will be fine. Also please don't forget to accept my answer :)